# How can I confirm if a process is being blocked from communicating on a network?

Tags: windows-xp, security, firewall, process

I have a user system with a third-party vendor product that needs to communicate with the network.  We're noticing symptoms that suggests that the program/process is being blocked from communicating on the network (so no bits ever hit the wire for this specific process).

I've checked the windows firewall and it appears to be working fine. Security software (Symantec) doesn't appear to be blocking (nor do I see anything in the logs for it) but I'm still convinced that something is blocking it.

How can I tell what could be interfering with this process?

I thought that TCPView from SysInternals might help but I don't think that has the ability to show what OTHER process is the source of the interference.

Comment: For "monitoring a process" try MS' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) :)

Comment: Have you used a packet monitor to see if the packets for that process are being generated and sent?  The problem may lie outside of the machine, such as a bad route or other security measures on the network.

Comment: @MikeNaylor Yes - Wireshark doesn't show any packets specific to that process leaving machine - yet logs on the application itself show that it's trying to initiate a HTTPS session and timing out. I'm able to reach the same destination fine from a web browser.  Hence why I'm suspecting that something local to the OS is blocking the process.

Comment: @techie007 Hehe, thanks.  The thought had crossed my mind but I didn't know if that would show blocks of this potential nature.  For example, would it show another process (e.g. foosecurity.exe) performing some action on my application (e.g. fooapplication.exe)?  I thought procmon was more for file system level interaction.

Comment: Being that Symantec is installed I'd recommend disabling it completely and then seeing if the communications get out.  From my past experience with Symantec software firewalls and security software the logging of what is blocked isn't 100% and it may be the culprit.  Is it only using HTTPS traffic or are other ports needed?

Comment: @MikeNaylor  Thanks.  I tried that and it didn't work. :-(  I was hoping for some tool that would allow me to have more visibility to these types of interactions so I could check for other processes potentially doing something. ...and that way, it would also help me troubleshoot in environments with completely different software.

Comment: have you run a netstat report to see how many processes are listening on port 443?  If you're not familiar with netstat the command-line command would be similar to the following:  netstat -ab >C:\netstatlog.txt     This writes to a text file so you can search instead of scrolling the command line.  I'd look to see if other applications are listening on the port for traffic then try stopping those applications one at a time.
It may be possible another application is consuming or blocking the traffic for HTTPS that the vendor's process is trying to send.

Comment: I think you should check the ports on which the process is trying to communicate (via netstat -b) and then you can try to connect to the machine from some other machine either on the network or outside the network via telnet or putty while specifying that port. If something's blocking it it will say connection refused but if it gets through you will get blinking cursor or see some strings (in telnet)